# Differing vote counts in Review -> Badge Progress

Tags: support, badges, review

Why are the vote counts different for Civic Duty and Electorate ? Is it a bug ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They count different things:

- Civic duty counts total votes; you need 300 votes on *questions **or** answers*, up or down.
- Electorate counts votes on questions **only**; you need 600 of those, and that has to be at least 25% of your total votes.

These counts are explained *in the UI*; hover over the badge and a tooltip appears:

[image: tooltip]

Comment: I find that inconsistent compared to the rest of the UI.

Comment: @AshRj: Would you rather have it not show counts at all?

Comment: No, it could show percentage/scaled progress taking into account both factors.

Comment: @AshRj: how do you propose to calculate a percentage of any form with that requirement?

Comment: @AshRj: What if the counts are already adjusted? For all we know the target number shown is `min(600, 25% of total votes)`?

Comment: @Mat Something like this -> `min(total_votes, 100*question_votes/total_votes)` with a toottip explaining the number or maybe even both the numbers (not just the min) once `Civic Duty` progress becomes redundant.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That would make sense.